# Detect GTK theme change in runtime

Tags: themes, indicator, python, application-development, icons

I am using [this code](https://github.com/umpirsky/revision-monitor/blob/master/revision_monitor/Indicator.py#L48) to set appropriate appindicator icon for my application. Basically I set separate mono dark/light icon for Ambiance and Radiance theme in order to integrate my app into Unity desktop just like many other apps do. This works well, but what I noticed is that other apps (Tomboy, thunderbird...) update their appindicator icons immediately after the theme is changed. How do they do that? 
With my current implementation, I need to restart my app in order to get the right icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tomboy does not actually have a code for detecting theme changes. Its icon changes automatically because there is a Tomboy icon both in the ubuntu-icon-dark icon theme (used by Ambiance) and in the ubuntu-icon-light icon theme (used by Radiance). That's the recommended way.

Comment: Yeah, but those themes do not provide icon for my app :)

Comment: Not by default, but you can add them by making your package install your icons on the /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-icon-dark and /usr/share/icons/ubuntu-icon-light folders.